# Summing data within a specified radius

Tags: qgis, shapefile, census

I have created a map to display 2011 census data using .shp files of output areas in England and Wales and joined this to a csv file which has the census data for each output area. I then display he data using graduated colours.

This works very well and displays maps showing the data for each output area.

Now I would like to also be able to display how many people who have attribute X within the output area, but also (separately) how many there are within a radius of N metres of each output area (let's say how many people there are over 65 within 1 mile of Output Area G (or the centre of the Output area if that is simpler)

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. Thank you for taking the Tour. The answer to most "Is there a way" questions is "Yes", so please focus on what you have attempted (making the buffers and overlaying them with the other data)